# ¿Por que el resultado de los metodos da 0 en mi operación?

Tags: java

Estoy hace dias revisando mi codigo y tratando de acomodarlo lo mas posible para no ser tan redundante y al probarlo no da el resultado esperado **cabe aclarar que los datos que uso para probar son datos ya probados** y por mas que leo y reescribo las formulas o trato de probar individualmente cada metodo de mi clase el resultado es siempre 0

```
    /*
     * efectivo a Nominal
     * 
     * TE=rate PTE=basePeriod p1=convertPeriod p2=compoundingPeriod
     */
    public double EffectiveToNominal() {
        System.out.println(rate);
        System.out.println(basePeriod);
        System.out.println(convertPeriod);
        System.out.println(compoundingPeriod);
        
        return (convertPeriod / compoundingPeriod) * (Math.pow(1 + rate, compoundingPeriod / basePeriod) - 1)*100;
    }

    /*
     * Nominal a efectivo J=rate p1=basePeriod Ps=convertPeriod p2=compoundingPeriod
     */
    public double NominalToEffective() {
        System.out.println(rate);
        System.out.println(basePeriod);
        System.out.println(convertPeriod);
        System.out.println(compoundingPeriod);
        
        return (Math.pow(1 + (rate / (basePeriod / compoundingPeriod)), convertPeriod / compoundingPeriod) - 1)*100;
    }

    /*
     * Efectiva a Efectiva i=rate Pd=basePeriod Ps=convertPeriod
     */
    public double EffectiveToEffective() {
        System.out.println(rate);
        System.out.println(basePeriod);
        System.out.println(convertPeriod);
        
        return (Math.pow(1 + rate, (convertPeriod / basePeriod)) - 1)*100;
    }

    // Nominal A Nominal
    public double NominalToNominal() {
        System.out.println(rate);
        System.out.println(basePeriod);
        System.out.println(convertPeriod);
        
        if (basePeriod > convertPeriod)
            return (rate / (basePeriod * convertPeriod))*100;
        else
            return (rate * (convertPeriod / basePeriod))*100;
    }
    
}
```

el codigo esta implementado con algunas ecepciones que en la clase Main uso para su funcionamiento

```
// Metodos Constructores
    public RateConversor(float rate, int bPeriod, int convPeriod, int cPeriod) {
        // metodo para Efectivo a nominal y nominal a efectivo
        setRate(rate);
        setBasePeriod(bPeriod);
        setConvertPeriod(convPeriod);
        setCompoundingPeriod(cPeriod);
    }

    public RateConversor(float rate, int bPeriod, int convPeriod) {
        // metodo para Efectivo a efectivo y Nominal a nominal
        setRate(rate);
        setBasePeriod(bPeriod);
        setConvertPeriod(convPeriod);
    }
```

la parte de la instanciación de la clase en Main

```
conv = new RateConversor(rate, bPeriod, convPeriod, compPeriod);
```

Un ejemplo minimo verificable del primer metodo

```
public class testeoEjemplo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //porcentaje de la tasa de interes
    double rate=0.02;
    //el periodo en dias inicial
    int basePeriod=120;
    //periodo en dias a convertir
    int convertPeriod=180;
    //periodo de capitalización
    int compoundingPeriod=60;
    double answer;
    
    answer=(convertPeriod / compoundingPeriod) * (Math.pow(1 + rate, compoundingPeriod / basePeriod) - 1)*100;
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Las variables están asignadas? Si no las asignas su valor por defecto es 0. Además, ¿con qué valores estás probando el código? y ¿cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Hola Mateo, si las variables son asignadas en el constructor del Main incluso puse unos outputs para verificar que esten asignadas.

tomemos de ejemplo que uso la primera opción efectivas a Nominales y le doy los valores de  2%(internamente en los metodos Setter lo divide entre 100 para hacer mas sencilla la conversión) 120 180 60 en el orden en como pide el constructor y espero un resultado de 3,0301%

Comment: ¿Podes agregar el constructor de la clase y la línea en que la instancias?

Comment: si ya agregue los constructores(2 metodos usan un parametro que los otros 2 no por eso 2 constructores)

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues un [example]

Comment: Lo copié bien pero al hacer el cálculo me da 2.985148, no 3.0301.

Comment: @Mateo hiciste algun cambio? estuve probando con Junit y con breakpoints para ver cad paso de el programa pero no arrojaba nada

Comment: @AndresGardiol si voy a intentar reducirlo a lo maximo posible para la primera formula

Comment: https://tio.run/##bZDBasMwEETv@oo9Sm6j2DmUgsknFAI5hh42lnDlyJKR1i6h5NudJYQ0SbsHLcwbaQZ1OOGiM4d5dv0QE0HHgvYYWl3UQjQec4ZNim3CHn7EMO69ayATEq8pOgM9uiC3lFxod5@Aqc2KjcBjIrstJCQLayh1uarv9T1mu7HJRcO0WpUPsIlhsol@@fsz57pjMJx687w9WdA3o48M5ONry7@3FRQgP5C@9BC/ZQUvl9av/8Qs73orWECliqq8Bl@O7TGT7XUcSQ/8KeSDvDZRtTiJ0zyfAQ

Comment: y es lo que no entiendo @Mateo si corriendo en otra parte si ejecuta pero en Eclipse no considero la posibilidad de que sea un error del IDE, algo raro pues hace no mucho ejecute otros codigos similares y ejecutaban perfectamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ejemplo en la función `main` usa variables enteras. Entonces en la parte `compoundingPeriod / basePeriod` se produce una división de enteros.

Teniendo en cuenta los valores de `compoundingPeriod` (60) y `basePeriod` (180), el resultado es 0 porque 60 < 180.

Todo número elevado a la 0 da 1, menos 1 da 0 y esa es la explicación del resultado.

---

La solución al problema es declarar las variables como `double` o convertir explícitamente alguna de las dos.

El lenguaje funciona así respecto a operaciones aritméticas: si los dos operandos son enteros, sucede una operación de enteros.

Si al menos uno de los 2 es un float o un double, se convierte implícitamente el otro.

El código de la clase está cortado, pero supongo que la causa es la misma.

Comment: GRACIAAS ni siquiera se me paso por la mente que estoy dividiendo enteros y los redondeaba pensaba que porque la asignación era a una variable de tipo double la divición no hacia el redondeo